# Error parsing type definition 'response': cannot find type definition: time.Duration (swaggo)

Tags: go, swagger, openapi

Using github.com/swaggo - librires for swagger documentation in go.
To generate doc trying to execute command in terminal -
**swag init -g /cmd/svr/main.go -o ./cmd/svr/docs**

while executing above command getting below error

```
   2023/07/17 11:35:52 Error parsing type definition 'response': cannot find type definition:      time.Duration
   2023/07/17 11:35:52 ParseComment error in file Desktop/work/api/api.go :cannot find type    definition: time.Duration
```

```
model
type response struct {
    Message        string        `json:"message,omitempty"`
    Data           interface{}   `json:"data,omitempty"`
    TimeTaken      time.Duration `json:"timeTaken"`
} // @name response
```

```
// @Description get data from file
// @ID Get Data
// @Accept */*
// @Produce json
// @Success 200 {object} response
// @Router /getv1 [get]
func (a API) getData()  {
//get logic code 
}
```

is swaggo librires wont support time.Duration type ?

Answer (score 2):

In `Swaggo`, [`ParseDependency` and `ParseInternal`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/swaggo/swag#Parser) are flags used with the swag init command to control how Swaggo generates documentation for your Go code.

- When you use the ParseDependency flag with swag init, Swaggo will generate Swagger documentation for external (third-party) packages that your project depends on. This can be useful if your code uses external packages, and you want to include documentation for them in your Swagger documentation.
- The ParseInternal flag, on the other hand, instructs Swaggo to generate Swagger documentation only for the internal packages of your project. It excludes any external dependencies. Use this flag when you want to focus solely on documenting your project's internal APIs and don't want to include documentation for third-party dependencies.

*Summary:*

If the struct is defined in a dependency package, use `--parseDependency`.

If the struct is defined in your main project, use `--parseInternal`.

And if you want to include both internal types/packages and types/packages from dependencies, you can use both flags together:

> swag init --parseDependency --parseInternal